# Set tabulators editorParams depending on the value of data from which table is populated

Tags: javascript, tabulator

So i am populating a table after getting data from database by tabulator.

For example, the multidimensional data array has following keys and data in every index[0-..] -

`["code", "notation", "ztotal"]`

I will only show `notation` and `ztotal` in the table, not `code`. But user can change `ztotal`.
There is 3 possibility for the dropdown list for `ztotal` which depends on the value of `code`. I want to do something as below, if possible

```
...blah blah
    {title: "NOTATION", field: "notation", frozen:true}
    {title: "ZTOTAL", field: "ztotal", editor: "select", editorParams:{values:getDropDown(code)}}
...blah blah
...
function getDropDown(code) {
    if(code == 1) return dropdown1;
    else if(code == 2) return dropdown2;
    else return dropdown3;
```

How do i achieve this?
Thanks is advance

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, guessed someone else will find it useful.

```
{title: "ZTOTAL", field: "ztotal", editor: "select", editorParams:{values:getDropDown}}
.........
function getDropDown(cell) {
    code = cell.getRow().getData()["field_name"];
    // dropdown1,2,3 contains array for pull down menu
    if(code == 1) return dropdown1;
    else if(code == 2) return dropdown2;
    else return dropdown3;
}
```